# high reCaptcha score by sending data automatically

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a google reCaptcha v3 included on a page
`#btn_populate` - fills form fields with some values
`#btn_send` - calls the reCaptcha response and sends data to remote server

Many say that reCaptcha works on basis of mouse mouvement, clicking inside a field, type on keyboard and so on
i.e. it is based on user interaction with the page

I put all the stuff inside a `document.ready` function
So there is no any user interaction
I suppose that a spam robot works like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_populate').click();
    $('#btn_send').click();
});
```

result - very high score from Google - `0.9`
means - sending data is super safe
any comment or explanation, pls

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#interpreting_the_score _"reCAPTCHA learns by seeing real traffic on your site. For this reason, scores in a staging environment or soon after implementing may differ from production."_

Comment: @ThomasSablik - my site is on a production level. `0.9` is very high and this is a real traffic - data is sent to database

Comment: This is a very specific question about google reCaptcha v3 but you didn't mention it in the title and in the tags. I don't even think this is the best platform for this question. I'd ask this question in a Google forum.

Comment: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/235 It looks like Google reCaptcha v3 doesn't work for many people.